# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 on ARM64 Odroid N2

Tags: sound, 20.04, ubuntu-studio, arm64

I am working on a new architecture and manufacturer and community are learning about Ubuntu issues.
I am using this distribution since 2016 but the ARM64 is slightly different in how hardware is
configured.
The 18.04 lts works but 20.04 lts is reconfigured and not behaving.
Where are best places to ask about troubleshooting the files needing review ?

The current wiki sound is [working on 18.04](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-n2/application_note/sound) but not technically explained when severely changed.
Issue is DTB is from 18.04 and ALSA is from 20.04 leading to loss of audio and their associated connections.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Ubuntu Studio for architectures other than AMD64. ARM64 is not a supported architecture for Ubuntu Studio.